# Attempting to Restore Database From ibd Files but Receiving Errors on Tablespace Import

Tags: innodb, mariadb, recovery

Recently, a customer (who didn't take backups of their system for whatever reason) had a database disaster so their production database had all of its files removed EXCEPT its ibd files. I have recovered databases using tablespace files through discarding and importing before but I have not had any luck and only hit errors when I try.

All tables except for a small number are InnoDB and the database engine is MariaDB 10.0.13.

When I do an import for any table, I receive this in return: `ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table <table>; try to repair it`. Being an InnoDB table, repair doesn't work.

Cursory research showed that as most likely being a disk space error. I had plenty of space but I stopped Maria, cleaned the temp directory and started it again then ran right into the same issue.

I pulled the entire data folder in-house to work with it. I replaced the missing files for the database in question and Maria started without any problems but I still cannot manipulate the data. Not even a select will run without crashing.

I tried another approach by comparing the table locations of the same table on a fresh database in a hex editor then updating the old ibd file to use the new tablespace ID. Maria was able to start but I get `InnoDB: No B+Tree found in tablespace` in the logs when the service starts.

I checked in `innodb_sys_tables`, `innodb_sys_tablespace` and `innodb_sys_indexes` in `information_schema` and nothing for that database is referenced. I'm reasonably certain that is a bad thing.

Are there any options left to attempt data recovery or has the production data been lost?

Comment: Did you have the `.frm` files?  Did you have a way to recreate the `CREATE TABLEs`?  A `.ibd` file has data and indexes, but not the schema (.frm); `ibdata1` contains a "table number".  But perhaps your import technique took care of most of that.

Comment: Yes. I have the table schema. Previously, I was able to structure an empty database then use `discard tablespace` and `import tablespace` to pull the data in and link it. This time, I get the key error I mentioned.

Comment: (I presume you meant "empty _table_".)  The table must have the _same_ indexes as the rest.

Comment: Database with empty tables. Should've been more clear. I would assume it has the same indexes since I used the same source. To which index are you referencing? I want to be sure I'm on the same page.

Comment: Please provide the SQL statement(s) involved in the "import".

Comment: I use these:  
`alter table <table> discard tablespace` and `alter table <table> import tablespace`.

Comment: No `.cfg` file available?  10.0 in all cases?

Comment: No cfg file and 10.0.13 for the source database and what I was using to work on it.